# Biztalk email Notification error.This Assembler cannot retrieve a document specification using this type: "html".

Tags: biztalk

Hi I am trying to send email notification . I have no attachment.

i am trying to send in body text with some content which is of type FF.

Name1  Designation1  sal
Name2  Designation   sal
Name3  Designation2  sal
Name4  Designation1  sal

its throwing below error , the same is wokring fine when i try to send single valued string in body text ex

```
strBodyText="some value";
msgJobDetailsEmail(SMTP.EmailBodyText) = strBodyText;
```

however the same text in FF formate i attach to strBodyText.its not worrking.

Error : 
"This Assembler cannot retrieve a document specification using this type: "html". "

Please advice .. thanks in advance.

my written code is as below ,

```
msgJobDetailsEmail = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
msgJobDetailsEmail.LoadXml("<html><body><p>Failed Message:</p><p>CON001</p></body></html>");
msgJobDetailsEmail(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.ContentType) = "text/html";

msgJobDetailsEmail(SMTP.Subject) = strSubject;

msgJobDetailsEmail(SMTP.EmailBodyText) = strBodyText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the Assembler component from the Send Pipeline, such as by using PassThrough Transmit.